# SHIFT + ` or SHIFT + ~ No longer works to controll camera with WASD?

Tags: camera

So normally I manage my camera animations by pressing SHIFT + ` and this usually works fine but I cannot get it to work can anyone help [image: My screen incase it helps]

Comment: did you check your preferences -> keymap whether the keys were changed?

Comment: did you maybe change your keymap? (with german keymap for example this is not realy feasable without rebinding)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under `Preferences` -> `Keymap` search for `Fly Mode` and click in the Field where it Says `Shift'` and rebind it to whatever you like to press.

call me oldscool... but for me `Shift F` for Flymode .. like it used to be works great